# Self referencing deferrable primary and foreign key in same table

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to make a foreign key reference to a primary key in the same table where the primary key is DEFERRABLE. It does not matter if the fk is deferrable. When I create the fk I get an error telling me it cant be created. I can't however find any reference to this not being allowed in the docs?

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t
( id integer
 ,txt text
 ,base integer
 ,CONSTRAINT t_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES
 (1, 'one', 2)
,(2, 'two', 1);

SELECT * FROM t; 

id | txt | base
---+-----+--
2  | one | 1
1  | two | 2
```

However if I now try and make base a fk to id I get the following error

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_base_fkey FOREIGN KEY (base) REFERENCES t (id)

>>> ERROR:  cannot use a deferrable unique constraint for referenced table "t"
```

Comment: Why don't you do the obvious thing and use a primary key that is not deferrable?

Comment: Why are you trying to make the primary key constraint of your table deferrable?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe because I need the PK to be deferrable and the base to be a fk, as shown in the example. Obviously.

Comment: @Bergi so I can switch the rows in one transaction as shown.

Comment: @jackwest What do you mean by "switch the rows"? I don't see any code in your question that would require the constraint to be deferred.

Comment: Well, you cannot have it. If you routinely update ("switch") primary keys, there is something wrong with your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

> REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ] [ MATCH matchtype ] [ ON DELETE referential_action ] [ ON UPDATE referential_action ] (column constraint)
> FOREIGN KEY ( column_name [, ... ] ) REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn [, ... ] ) ] [ MATCH matchtype ] [ ON DELETE referential_action ] [ ON UPDATE referential_action ] (table constraint)

> These clauses specify a foreign key constraint, which requires that a group of one or more columns of the new table must only contain values that match values in the referenced column(s) of some row of the referenced table. If the refcolumn list is omitted, the primary key of the reftable is used. **The referenced columns must be the columns of a non-deferrable unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table.** ...

Emphasis mine.